# Is it possible to constrain two widgets inside a linear layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

My layout is a Constraint layout, but inside I have a cardview and inside of it I created a linear layout, so I can position images in a row (this is just the first image with its X button):

[image]

I would like each image (there should be 3 in a row) to have an X button. The X button should be inside each image like so:

[image]

I prefer using a linear layout so that the images will be independent of each other (later they will be movable).

I would like to attach an X button to the image, within its contours, which was very simple to do within a constraint layout, but impossible to do inside a linear layout? Is there an alternative for constraining the X button inside the image?

My current XML:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.EditProfileActivity">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/grey"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profilePic1"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/profile_pic1">
            </ImageView>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/deletePic1"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/delete_picture_button_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/delete_picture_button_size"
                android:background="@drawable/delete_button"
                android:translationX="5dp"
                android:translationY="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/profilePic1"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/profilePic1" />


        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: To display view above other view, you can use FrameLayout, RelativeLayout or ConstrainLayout. LinearLayout is only used when you want to show views side by side or from top to bottom

Comment: Thanks Duy I don't want to display view above view, I want to display views side by side (horizontally) but that each imageView will have the X button constrained to it

Comment: I added a screenshot of how I would like the X button in relation to the image

Answer (score 2):

you can do it using ConstraintLayout inside CardView :

```
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profilePic1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/profilePic2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_person" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
            android:id="@+id/deletePic1"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@drawable/style_white_cornar"
            android:translationX="5dp"
            android:translationY="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/profilePic1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/profilePic1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profilePic2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/profilePic3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/profilePic1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_person" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
            android:id="@+id/deletePic2"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@drawable/style_white_cornar"
            android:translationX="5dp"
            android:translationY="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/profilePic2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/profilePic2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profilePic3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/profilePic2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_person" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
            android:id="@+id/deletePic3"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@drawable/style_white_cornar"
            android:translationX="5dp"
            android:translationY="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/profilePic3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/profilePic3" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using ConstraintLayout inside CardView like this :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profilePic1"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/square_pipe_icon" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
        android:id="@+id/deletePic1"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/delete_picture_button_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/delete_picture_button_size"
        android:background="@drawable/delete_button"
        android:translationX="5dp"
        android:translationY="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/profilePic1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/profilePic1" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: But it's not working if I create a constraint layout for each image, and if I use the constraint layout for all the 3, then again I need to constrain them to the cardview which might cause problems. I tried to ask if there is an option to constrain the X button inside the image within a linear layout

Answer (score 1):

Use `FrameLayout` not `LinearLayout`

do something like this

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            />

    </FrameLayout>
```